# external stylesheet CSS cannot be linked

Tags: css, html, hyperlink

I know this question has been asked before, because I already checked the forum. I cannot link my CSS to my HTML5 code. I tried running my code in different browsers and cleaning the cache, but nothing worked.

This is my code in HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>External Style sheet </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
     </head>


     <body>
        <h1>Intro to CSS</h1>
        <p> I'm blue</p>
        <p>I can be any colour you want me to</p>
        <p>I know you only wanna use me as a <br>example</br></p>
     </body>


</html>
```

and my CSS

```
p{
    color:red;
}

h1{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: "cache" doesn't have an accent

Comment: Is the CSS file named "main.css" and placed in the same folder as the HTML?

Comment: See [Quackit](https://www.quackit.com/css/external_style_sheets.cfm) and [W3Schols](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) on referencing an external CSS file

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools & network tab?

Comment: yes, my css file is name main and they're both in th same folder

Comment: @SLaks where do I check that info?

Comment: Right-click in Chrome, Inspect Element

Comment: @SLaks in network tab I see number from 20 ms up to 100 ms, and nothing else.

Comment: oh, wait. I select the Css tag and in status  it says "failed"

Comment: net::ERR_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Look at the URL and response and figure out why it failed.

Comment: ok, idk if this may be the problrm. When I save the archive,  select the option CSS(*.css;*css,erb;*.css,liquid), then if I check the type of the file it shows 'archive' instead of CSS

Comment: Request URL: file:///C:/Users/unknow/Desktop/html5/main.CSS
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my code was ok, the problem was the way I was saving my CSS  file, I was selecting the file type  CSS(.css;*css,erb;.css,liquid) which made sense to me since I was trying to save a CSS file, but no. I only had to select the option all files and name it by myself as main.css. after that, my code run perfectly